# WPF combobox custom control text search functionality

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am having a cutom combo box control in my WPF MVVM application and I am trying to enable serach in the box. This means whenever a user will type anything on the cmb box it will display those pertainig records.

I am using below code but unable to see this working.

```
<ComboBox x:Class="ABC.Selector"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ABC.ViewModels"
        TextSearch.TextPath ="{Binding Name}" IsEditable="True">
 >
 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

This functionality works with below code :

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="cmb" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="9"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Details}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TextSearch.TextPath>Name</TextSearch.TextPath>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding}">
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                                <Binding Path="Name" />
                                <Binding Path="LongName" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Any idea how to enable this in first code block ?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes. I want to enable this in my first code block.

Answer (score 0):

`TextPath` does not expect a binding to the actual value; it expects the **name of the property** to search.  You should set `TextSearch.TextPath="Name"`.

Comment: I did  TextSearch.TextPath ="Name" but it is not working. what could be the catch ?

Comment: Each item in your `Details` collection has a `Name` property, yes?  And that is the property you want to search?  If so, this should work.

Comment: Ideally it should work but this is not working at all. I am not sure where I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox x:Name="vendorCombo"  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.VendorMasterSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}}"                                                     
                                                SelectedValue="{Binding VendorNo,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                SelectedValuePath="VENDOR_MASTER_ID"  
                                                        behaviour:ComboBoxSeletionChangedBehaviour.ComboBoxSeletionChangedCommand=
                                                  "{Binding DataContext.SelectionChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}}" TextSearch.TextPath="NAME"   IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True" >
                                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NUMBER}"/>
                                                            <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NAME}"/>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            </ComboBox>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of your answer?

Comment: @phuzi sure i can, Use these three for the combobox to work as search box. `TextSearch.TextPath="NAME" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True"` and this should enable search for you!.